# $N(R) \subset \operatorname{ann}_R (M)$ if M is simple left module

Tags: modules

> $N(R) \subset \operatorname{ann}_R (M)$ if M is simple left module

How do I prove this?

Know that if $a$ is in $N(R)$, then $a^n=0$ for some element. However, don't see how to go from this.

$N(R)=\sum \{ I\}$ where I is nilpotent ideal of R.

Comment: It would not hurt if you edited the question to add an explanation of what $N(R)$ is...

Comment: Could you say what $N(R)$ is? It's my understanding that the nilpotent elements might not form an ideal in the non-commutative setting.

Comment: @Dylan, in the quotient $A$ of the free algebra $k\langle x,y\rangle$ by the bilateral ideal $(x^2,y^2)$, the (classes of) $x$ and $y$ are nilpotent, but their sum isn't.

Comment: @Mariano Ah, thanks! Good to have an example.

Answer (score 2):

From your definition of $N(R)$ it is enough to show that $I \subset \text{ann}_R(M)$ for every nilpotent ideal $I$.
So let $I$ be nilpotent and suppose $IM \neq \{0\}$. As $IM$ is a submodule of $M$
and $M$ is simple you get $IM = M$. By induction you get $I^nM = M$ for all $n$ but with $I$ being nilpotent you get $M = \{0\}$ a contradiction to $IM \neq{0}$.